# MySQLdb format query parameters without executing?

Tags: string-formatting, mysql-python

MySQLdb formats query parameters using a `%s` notation:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = %s and baz = %s', (10, "spam"))
```

Is there a way to generate the formatted query without executing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, MySQLdb uses `db.literal` to convert each parameter and then uses the query as a format string with the converted arguments:

```
query = query % tuple(db.literal(item) for item in args)
```